# Adding EMF Client Platform ModelExplorerView to application

Tags: java, eclipse, emf

I am currently building a simple Eclipse RCP product and would like to use components from the EMF client platform. I could not succeed on adding the ModelExplorerView to my Application.e4xmi file. What is the correct class URI for that view? I expected it to be `bundleclass://org.eclipse.emf.ecp.ui/org.eclipse.emf.ecp.ui.views.ModelExplorerView` but that gives me the runtime error: 
`org.eclipse.emf.ecp.ui.views.ModelExplorerView cannot be found by org.eclipse.emf.ecp.ui_1.8.0.20160208-2127`

Comment: I think that view is a 3.x view and won't work as a MPart in the Application.e4xmi

Comment: As there is a demo e4 application, the view must be available. By browsing through the Application.e4xmi of that demo, the class path might be `bundleclass://org.eclipse.emf.ecp.ui.e4/org.eclipse.emf.ecp.ui.e4.view.ECPModelView`. I might try to build my application by using that demo as a base, but without more documentation on EMFCP it will be quite painful :(

Comment: Just because it can generate an e4 app doesn't mean the code itself is e4. ModelExplorerView extends org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart which makes it 3.x code.